# how to save the values ​of a variable after using a method?

Tags: python

The program determines the type of triangle on three sides. sides must be entered in Roman letters. Capital letters work. I can't change them to smaller ones. Thanks in advance

```
import roman
print ("enter triangle side:")
a = (input("a = "))
b = (input("b = "))
c = (input("c = "))

def aww(a,b,c):
   if a.islower() or b.islower() or c.islower():
   return (str.capitalize(a)) or (str.capitalize(b)) or (str.capitalize(c))

aww(a,b,c)


def dsdj(a,b,c):

 if (a + b > c) and ((a + c) > b) and ((b + c) > a):
    if ((roman.fromRoman(c)) ^ 2) > ((roman.fromRoman(a)) ^ 2) + ((roman.fromRoman(b)) ^ 2):
    print("obtuse triangle")

    elif ((roman.fromRoman(c))) ^ 2 == ((roman.fromRoman(a)) ^ 2) + ((roman.fromRoman(b)) ^ 2):
        print("Right triangle")
    else:

    print("Acute Triangle")

 else:
    return "Error"
```

dsdj(a,b,c)

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the problem, is there an error?
If the problem is that a, b, c is not capitalized, then it's because you called the function, yet doesn't assign the values. Try to use `a, b, c = aww(a,b,c)`, and also change `aww` so it returns `(str.capitalize(a)),  (str.capitalize(b)), (str.capitalize(c))` and not `or`.

Comment: roman.InvalidRomanNumeralError: Invalid Roman numeral: i

Comment: Then the capitalization isn't working. The previous comment is supposed to work.

Comment: don't you need to convert to integers before your if line? as it stands, `if (a + b > c) and ((a + c) > b) and ((b + c) > a)` is doing some string operations. In any case, it may be worth having a function to convert to integers and move all the logic for conversion out of your function to determine what type of triangle it is.

Comment: Your indentation is flawed which will lead to a syntax error. Also, your use of *or* in the *aww()* function is almost certainly not what you wanted. The *return* needs to be indented. However, even when you've fixed that, the function will only ever return the capitalised version of *a*. Can you see why?

Answer (score 0):

First. Strings are immutable. You're ignoring the return values of the calls to `str.capitalize`, which means they get ignored. Easier would be to just call capitalize like this:

```
a = input("a = ").capitalize()
b = input("b = ").capitalize()
c = input("c = ").capitalize()
```

Next, in Python `a ^ b` is not exponentiation, it is the bitwise XOR operation (like in C). You will have to use `a ** b` instead.

Third, you always need to convert from roman numerals so `(a + b > c) and ((a + c) > b) and ((b + c) > a)` will not do what you want. Better use this:

```
import roman
print ("enter triangle side:")
a = roman.fromRoman(input("a = ").capitalize())
b = roman.fromRoman(input("b = ").capitalize())
c = roman.fromRoman(input("c = ").capitalize())

if a + b > c and a + c > b and b + c > a:
    if c ** 2 > a ** 2 + b ** 2:
        print("obtuse triangle")
    elif c ** 2 == a ** 2 + b ** 2:
        print("Right triangle")
    else:
        print("Acute Triangle")

 else:
    print("Not a triangle")
```

---

Also, if the `roman` library needs numbers like this: `VII` instead of like this: `Vii`, you need to use `.upper()` instead of `.capitalize()`. Capitalize means make the first letter of each word upper case rather than every letter.